# How can I initialize a Vue page in a jQuery Mobile application?

Tags: jsp, jquery-mobile, vuejs2

I am working on an application that has been left over by a consultant. The site is currently based on jQuery, but some of the logic on these pages is getting really complex, and the corresponding javascript is getting a little bit out of hand. I want to get rid of some of the plumbing that I have to do manually with jQuery Mobile by rewriting the pages in Vue.

I don't want to rewrite the whole site, only a few pages that could help me tame the complex logic and compartmentalize the code. I've dealt with all the jQuery enhancement conflicts for various components, but I am now facing a problem with jQuery's page loading mechanism.

When I navigate to the site written with Vue, the first time it loads, everything initializes properly and the code works just fine. However, upon navigating away and then going back to that page, nothing seems to work. It just looks like Vue has not initialized at all.

I would post an example, but I just don't know how post an example that requires navigation to show the problem, so the best thing I can do is describe reproduction steps:

1. Start off with any application with jQuery Mobile and a single page rewritten in Vue.
2. Navigate into the Vue page. Page works as expected.
3. Navigate away from the page back into the main jQM app.
4. Navigate back into the Vue page. This time Vue has not initialized correctly. All the HTML elements are still there, but Vue will not interact with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the cause of this problem, and since it technically works, I will post it as an answer. I know you're not supposed to mix jQuery Mobile and Vue, and all the compatibility issues are the main reason why, but I just don't have the luxury of starting from scratch and I still want the benefits that I get as a developer from the framework.

The problem here is jQM's caching/SPA architecture. I have a JSP application of which I am rewriting a single page in Vue. The root instance of the vue application is written out right into the JSP page, so when the user loads the page, it fetches the HTML with the template. Let's suppose for instance that this is the template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- links and scripts -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="content" class="ui-container">
        <div id="vue-application">
          <input v-model="test_input">
          <p>{{ test_input }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in `app.js`

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
  new Vue({
    el: "#vue-application",
    data: {
      test_input: ""
    }
  });
});
```

Given the above page, loading the first time works because the template is loaded untouched from the server into the DOM and then when Vue is initialized at `div#vue-application` it pulls the template out of the DOM, parses it out and initializes it, then mounts the Vue component back into the DOM without all the template syntax.

Now when you navigate away from the page, jQM will take whatever is in the DOM inside that `div[data-role=page]` element and cache it. Subsequent navigation to this page will not pull the unaltered template out of the server but instead will reinsert it into the DOM from memory, but the problem is that Vue has already replaced all the template code with normal DOM elements and all the hooks are now gone. All the events like `pageinit` still fire and Vue still initializes, but now there's no template to initialize, it's just a plain DOM, so Vue basically doesn't hook into anything and just kind of initializes a static HTML page.

To counteract this caching, I ended up loading the contents of `div#vue-application` through Ajax and initializing the application afterwards. The main page has been split up into two files:

`main_page.jsp`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- links and scripts -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="content" class="ui-container">
        <div id="vue-application"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`template.jsp`

```
<input v-model="test_input">
<p>{{ test_input }}</p>
```

and the javascript code also needed a bit of a rehaul:

`app.js`

```
$(document).bind("pageshow", function() {
  $.mobile.loading("show");
  $.ajax({
    url: "template.jsp",
    method: "Get",
    data: {
      // My JSPs are parameterized, so the template may
      // need some of the parameters from this page to 
      // be passed down into the template for initialization.
    }
  }).done(function(template) {
    initialize_vue_from_template("#vue-application", template);
  }).always(function() {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
  });
});

function initialize_vue_from_template(element, template) {
  $(element)
      .html(template)
      // Don't forget to initialize jQuery
      .enhanceWithin(); 

  new Vue({
    el: element,
    data: {
      test_input: ""
    }
  });
}
```

This seems to work. I doubt it's that great of a solution, but I figure if it is functional, I may as well include it here. If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to hear it.